# crash with doesNotRecognizeSelector with avplayeritem

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, avqueueplayer

I am getting a crash in what looks like a callback from an AVPlayerItem.
I set the notification like this:

```
if (queuePlayer==nil) {
    queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:playerItems];
}
else {
    for (AVPlayerItem* item in playerItems) {
        [queuePlayer insertItem:item afterItem:nil];
    }
}
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                 selector:@selector(playerLastItemDidReachEnd:)
                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                 object:[playerItems lastObject]];

[queuePlayer play];   
[playerItems release];
```

I get this crash in a random manner; meaning that most of the time, the code works. but it will generate this stack trace once in a while.

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30fbd350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3916a11e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x391a696e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x32515d4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x32512ff4 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x336c9a74 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x32513078 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x32513110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3251450e __cxa_throw + 118
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x336c99ba objc_exception_throw + 90
10  CoreFoundation                  0x353bce02 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 166
11  CoreFoundation                  0x353bb52c ___forwarding___ + 388
12  CoreFoundation                  0x35312f64 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3530a034 _CFXNotificationPost + 1424
14  AVFoundation                    0x317e6d60 __avplayeritem_fpItemNotificationCallback_block_invoke_0 + 3364
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x340aa11c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x340a94b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x340ae1b8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 220
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3538cf36 __CFRunLoopRun + 1286
19  CoreFoundation                  0x352ffeb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
20  CoreFoundation                  0x352ffd44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
21  GraphicsServices                0x3583c2e6 GSEventRunModal + 70
22  UIKit                           0x366de2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
23  Training                        0x0004399a main (main.m:14)
24  Training                        0x0004395c start + 36
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to debug the issue precisely.  Do you unregister for the notification in `-dealloc` for this class?

Comment: It would be kind of nice if you quoted the exact error message.

Comment: I agree, more code is needed to debug. For example, can you post your `playerLastItemDidReachEnd:` method definition?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn’t look like your object actually has a playerLastItemDidReachEnd: selector.